# Flip the commented-out code

Tags: c, c++, c#, java

This puzzle works for any programming language that has the same `//` single-line and `/* ... */` multi-line comments that C++, C# and Java do.

You are debugging an application. You find a fishy block of code, which you comment out and replace with some new code:

```
/*
code block A
*/
code block B
```

After some debugging, you find that you need to step through block A again to see how it worked. This requires quite a lot of cursor movement:

```
                ← remove “/*” here
code block A
/*              ← change “*/” to “/*” here
code block B
*/              ← add “*/” here
```

This is very laborious if you need to keep switching between block A and block B. So you decide to find a better way.

Place combinations of asterisks and slashes before block A, between the blocks, and after block B, such that you can flip between block A and block B by adding/removing only one character in one place. You may assume that the code blocks A and B do not contain any `/*` or `*/`.

There are two possible solutions.

Comment: Or use the pre-processor to do the job it was designed for! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Toggle commented out blocks by adding/removing the last slash on the first line:

```
/**/
code block A
/*/
code block B
/**/
```

Bonus solution, toggle this one by adding/removing the first slash on the first line:

```
//*
code block A
/*/
code block B
/**/
```

Comment: Double-bonus: The last line in each case may be replaced by `//*/`, giving four distinct solutions :)

Comment: It is your second solution that I’ve always used, and bobthecow’s variation on it that I knew of. Congratulations for finding another solution I hadn’t yet encountered! :)